# Zend_Form values are lost when using multiple forms in same page

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I use Zend Framework 1.12 on one of my projects. I need to use multiple forms in one page, and successfully managed to place them with the help of "render" function.

```
    $this->oneAction();
    $this->render('one');

    $this->anotherAction();
    $this->render('another');
```

There are two different actions for two forms, and in my indexAction() I call them like above. Two actions have their own scripts, and this code works well for placing 2 forms in one page.

Problem is; 2 different forms, with their own submit buttons (with different names), when second form is submitted, page reloads as a whole (naturally), but values in the first form's fields are lost.. I wrote a function to load some default values (for some fields of 1st form, taken from db) , and then it takes the values, but gives the error (Value is required and can't be empty) even they're filled by my function. I have to create a complex page with many forms, and can not go further with this problem.. 
I'd like to get a solution for this problem, or just little understanding about Zend Form's behavior about these multiple form submissions.

(There are many pages about these issues, but most of them just consider about placing multiple forms in same page, and no much more..)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to leverage Zend's Sub Forms.  Forms and sub-forms are practically the same thing in ZF, main differences being the use of the form decorator.  Much more powerful though to think of all of your forms as sub-forms that can be combined into a single form.  The following code provides an example:

```
class My_Master_Form extends ZendX_JQuery_Form
{   

    /**
     * combine sub forms into composite
     */
    public function  __construct($options = null)    
    {       
        parent::__construct($options);        

        // Add a sub form...
        $subform = new My_Foo_Form();       
        $subform->setElementsBelongTo('mySubForm');
        $subform->removeDecorator('Form');
        $subform->setOrder(-2);
        $this->addSubform($subform, 'mySubForm');

        ...
```

You would then render the single, master form.  Handling validation is straightforward. Existing code should iterate over each sub-form when performing validation.  You could override if needed and look at the failures in each sub-form after initial validation and summarize as needed if validation logic transcends across sub-forms.

Comment: Thank you. I have now subforms and a form to include subforms. But still cannot do the validation. I create the "master" form and subforms inside one action, and add the subforms to master form in same action. Also in same action, there is validation codes for forms. Viewing alright, 1 st form works alright (validation works) but second form cannot be validated. Their validation works same way. 
`if ($request->isPost()) {
   if ($infoform->isValid($request->getPost())) {..}
   if ($anotherform->isValid($request->getPost())) {..}            
}  `
What should be the problem here ?

Comment: After you have created that composite "master" Zend_Form you should proceed to treat it as a single entity.  For example you render the "master" form, you don't call render on each sub-form.  You should populate and validate the form the same way.  Note the code of `public function isValid` on `Zend_Form` and that the validation loops over all the sub-forms.